# No comma after last element in array?

Tags: php, arrays

I noticed that some arrays don't have a comma after the last item. I have an array:

```
$first_name = array(
              'name'        => 'first_name',
              'id'          => 'first_name',
              'maxlength'   => '20',             
              'class'       => 'text',
              'placeholder' => 'First name',
            );
```

I have a comma but no php errors. Should I keep or remove the comma?

Comment: It is a valid PHP syntax. It's strange but even experienced PHP programmers sometimes confused with this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a style preference as mentioned elsewhere, however I would advise to condition yourself against adding that trailing comma in PHP, as it is syntactically invalid in some languages.  In particular, I'm thinking of Internet Explorer's handling of those types of trailing commas in Javascript, which are notoriously difficult bugs to locate when scripts fail in IE while succeeding everywhere else. It will also break JSON's validity, and is invalid in a SQL `SELECT` list, among other potential problems.

Again, it's a matter of preference, but could cause you problems in other areas.

Comment: I agree with this -- IE7 with JS has bitten me before as described by Michael

Comment: And it's not fair only to pick on IE here. SQL scripts will also fail with trailing commas, but the RDBMS will at least give a useful error message most of the time.

Comment: Thank you! I actually had that sort of js error in Explorer a week ago. :)

Comment: Please do not say for the ALL languages(!) For example, Python is allowed to do so.

Comment: @socketpair You misunderstood the phrasing - in saying "_as it is not valid in all languages_" what is meant is "_it is invalid in some languages while valid in others_". Without specifically listing any languages where it _is_ valid (such as python, PHP) this was meant to inform that sometimes it will fail.  "_not valid in all_" was never intended to mean "_invalid in all_" as you have interpreted it.  You may always propose edits to old questions for corrections, anwyway.

Comment: I wish all languages would allow ending commas. When you frequently edit a list, you're bound to either forget a comma or add one at the end. A comma should mean "this is where this the element ends, and where a potential next element would begin regardless of whether it exists or not." Ending braces will let the program know the end of the list. JavaScript arrays seem to be OK with ending commas.

Answer (score 6):

The comma after last element may not work in every language. However it make diffs in version control systems cleaner for supported languages.

```
/* From */
$a = array(
    'element_w',
    'element_x',
);
/* To */
$a = array(
    'element_w',
    'element_x',
    'element_y', /* Only this line will show in version control. */
);


/* From */
$a = array(
    'element_w',
    'element_x'
);
/* To */
$a = array(
    'element_w',
    'element_x', /* These two lines               */
    'element_y'  /* will show in version control. */
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Both are syntactically correct in a number of languages.  The last element is ignored if left blank.  It is a nice little easter egg built into languages just so you don't have to keep adding in `,` before you start modifying an array if you manually have to add a few more values in.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a style preference if both are syntactically correct