# Why PHP Solr extension gives exception "Unsuccessful query request"

Tags: php, exception, solr

I use [PHP Solr extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/solr) and it when I run the code below I get the exception:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SolrClientException' with message 'Unsuccessful query request : Response Code 404.

I do not understand, what is wrong, I also use Solr client successfully.

```
include "bootstrap.php";

$options = array
(
    'hostname' => SOLR_SERVER_HOSTNAME,
    'login'    => SOLR_SERVER_USERNAME,
    'password' => SOLR_SERVER_PASSWORD,
    'port'     => SOLR_SERVER_PORT,
);

$client = new SolrClient($options);    
$query = new SolrQuery();   
$query->setQuery('lucene');    
$query->setStart(0);    
$query->setRows(50);    
$query->addField('cat')->addField('features')->addField('id')-> addField('timestamp');    
$query_response = $client->query($query);    
$response = $query_response->getResponse();    
print_r($response);    
?>
```

**my bootstrap.php file is:**

```
<?php

/* Domain name of the Solr server */
//define('SOLR_SERVER_HOSTNAME', 'solr.example.com');//solr.example.com
define('SOLR_SERVER_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');//solr.example.com


define('SOLR_SECURE', true);


/* HTTP Port to connection */
//define('SOLR_SERVER_PORT', ((SOLR_SECURE) ? 8443 : 8983));
define('SOLR_SERVER_PORT', ((SOLR_SECURE) ? 8080 : 8443));

/* HTTP Basic Authentication Username */
define('SOLR_SERVER_USERNAME', '');//admin

/* HTTP Basic Authentication password */
define('SOLR_SERVER_PASSWORD', '');//changeit

/* HTTP connection timeout */
/* This is maximum time in seconds allowed for the http data transfer operation. Default value is 30 seconds */
define('SOLR_SERVER_TIMEOUT', 10);

/* File name to a PEM-formatted private key + private certificate (concatenated in that order) */
define('SOLR_SSL_CERT', 'certs/combo.pem');

/* File name to a PEM-formatted private certificate only */
define('SOLR_SSL_CERT_ONLY', 'certs/solr.crt');

/* File name to a PEM-formatted private key */
define('SOLR_SSL_KEY', 'certs/solr.key');

/* Password for PEM-formatted private key file */
define('SOLR_SSL_KEYPASSWORD', 'StrongAndSecurePassword');

/* Name of file holding one or more CA certificates to verify peer with*/
define('SOLR_SSL_CAINFO', 'certs/cacert.crt');

/* Name of directory holding multiple CA certificates to verify peer with */
define('SOLR_SSL_CAPATH', 'certs/');
```

Comment: This does not explain the late exception, but your $options array should produce errors. The last row contains an ending comma which is not allowed. Could it be linked?

Comment: @Daniel: You are wrong. there is no problem in PHP having that comma, it's not Json, it is PHP. See [No comma after last element in array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6146713/367456)

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar error message when I query Solr.

The error came from that I am using a collection and therefore you need to specify it in your configuration:

```
$options = array
(
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'login'    => '',
        'password' => '',
        'port'     => 8983,
        'path'     => 'solr/collection', // <-- Add your collection here
);
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

What I can see as a problem is the line

```
define('SOLR_SERVER_PORT', ((SOLR_SECURE) ? 8080 : 8443));
```

is your secure connection using port 8080 or 8443?
I assume that the normal connection is 8080 and secure is 8443, but the line implies the opposite, the  secure port is 8080 and normal one  is 8443